# Understanding STL includes and how the compilation/preprocessing works

Tags: c++, stl, preprocessor

I was investigating STL implementations, and I'm failing to understand how the code compiles.

Take `std::set` as an example. [Here's a reference to libstdc++ on github.](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3832c6f7e672e76bba74a508bf3a49740ea38046/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_set.h).

Internally, `std::set` uses a red-black tree, using `class _Rb_tree`, lines 131-133.

It appears `class _Rb_tree` is defined in stl_tree.h, available [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3832c6f7e672e76bba74a508bf3a49740ea38046/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_tree.h), line 425.

I'm confused because `stl_set.h` does not include `stl_tree.h`. Why does this not fail?

Comment: you are looking at implementation details. Usually one writes headers such that they include what they need. But thats just convenience / convention. One can write headers that only work when other headers have been included before and that seems to be the case here

Comment: I notice that its implementation of `<set>` includes both of these headers. It's beyond me why this header isn't self-sufficient, though.

Comment: @chris Possible future use, especially of the red-black tree. It's separation of concerns, nothing more.

Comment: @sweenish, To be clear, I specifically mean `stl_set.h` being self-sufficient in terms of including its dependencies. Splitting the tree implementation off makes sense to me, but it would be conventional for `stl_set.h` to include the implementation header itself because the code in `stl_set.h` is already directly dependent on the implementation type. I'd be interested to see the original reason for breaking convention, which I didn't find from a cursory glance at the file's commit history.

Comment: I actually do not see a convention being broken here. The convention is to make headers that users include selfcontained. For internal not-meant-to-be-included-by-users headers it is sometimes not even possible to do that. What you do in such case is to provide a to-be-user-included header that includes the necessary headers in right order, and thats the case here

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the header that is actually exposed and meant to be used, [`<set>`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3832c6f7e672e76bba74a508bf3a49740ea38046/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/set#L62), you can see that `stl_tree.h` is included just before `stl_set.h` and so a file that includes that main header will compile without any issue.

Answer (score 3):

It does not fail, because you are looking at implementation details and  you arent supposed to include `stl_set.h` directly. You do include [`<set>`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3832c6f7e672e76bba74a508bf3a49740ea38046/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/set) which does include both of those headers.

I suppose you are confused because typically a header includes what it uses. That way one can make sure there are no hidden dependencies. Including that one header is sufficient to use it.

However, thats just what is good practice / convention. Nothing (but conventions) forbids you to write two headers like this:

```
# foo.h
struct foo { bar b; }

# bar.h
struct bar {};
```

To use them one has to include both in the right order:

```
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"

foo f;  // works !!
```

Of course you should not write headers like that when they are supposed to be included by other code. If you are in a situation like this then you should write a thrid header:

```
# foobar.h
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"
```

And now users of your code can include `foobar.h` and need not worry about the order of includes.

Comment: I'm not asking about including it directly. I'm wondering why the preprocessor doesn't error when processing stl_set.h.

Comment: @andy why would the preprocessor produce an error? THe preprocessor only processes the preprocessor instructions. It sees an `#include` then it includes the contents of the file, thats basically it

Comment: @andy moreover the preprocessor only sees the files in right order when a user includes `set` and all is fine. Sorry I dont get what should fail

Comment: Ok, I assumed it was best practice to not depend on order of includes. I guess it's okay here because one should only `#include <set>`, and that file does includes in the correct order.